# FreeForm Entries Pagination Not Working

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

FreeForm pagination only works if the entry results of the form is MORE than the limit. If the results are not greater than the limit i get a loop of code.

For example: I have a total of only 5 entries in the form.. however in due time there will be more...

When i limit to 10... I would expect to see no pagination links until my results exceeds 10. At the moment though i get a continuous loop of the following code.

```
{freeform:paginate}
Page {freeform:current_page}
of {freeform:total_pages}
pages &nbsp;
{freeform:pagination_links}
{/freeform:paginate}
```

If i set my limit to for example.. "2" the paginaiton works perfectly (because i have more entries than "2").

Can anyone shed some light on this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can confirm this issue on our end as well. It's a bug and we'll get a fix out for it soon. In the meantime, the workaround suggested above will resolve the issue for now (wrapping conditional around pagination code):

```
{if freeform:paginate}{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap the pagination tag in a conditional.

```
{if freeform:paginate}
    {freeform:paginate}
        Page {freeform:current_page} of {freeform:total_pages} pages &nbsp; {freeform:pagination_links}
    {/freeform:paginate}
{/if}
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks, I will try when I'm at my desk.